# How to translate python code to javascript with PYJS

Tags: javascript, python, compiler-construction, pyjamas

Hi I have some code in python that I need to rewrite in Javascript. There are a few math functions and instead of reinventing the wheel I would like to see how pyjs converts them.

I have had a look at the pyjs setup and documentation but it is aimed at producing on the fly websites. How do I setup and use pyjs simply to convert a .py file into .js?

Comment: pyjamas is really a ported version of GWT, google widget or something of the likes, not a pure encompassing Python -> JS. I don't think the translator has any really high level functionality but you can try it. Maybe you could write your own abstracted API for the needed math functions that is accessible by pyjs